# Php artisan optimize error after updateing laravel from 5.3 to 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.6, laravel-artisan

[image: screenshot]

Using Laravel 5.6, yesterday I updated to 5.6 from 5.3, after updating appeared this bug.

Comment: There is no `composer optimize` command. What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: It would be preferable to post the command and error message as text so it can be found by others facing the same problem.

Comment: @rob006 oh, i uploaded other screen, i try to to php artisan optimize, and answer is Command "optimize" is not defined.

Comment: @filburt thank you for u're comment, i try to do command php artisan optimize.

Answer (score 1):

There was `php artisan optimize` command but it was removed in Laravel 5.6

In [Laravel 5.6 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) you can read:

> The optimize Command
>
> The previously deprecated optimize Artisan command has been removed.
>   With recent improvements to PHP itself including the OPcache, the
>   optimize command no longer provides any relevant performance benefit.
>   Therefore, you may remove php artisan optimize from the scripts within
>   your composer.json file.

Comment: Thank you :) really great answer